# how to calculate current datetime and given datetime using php?

Tags: php, datetime

I want to get difference time from current date time. Example :
my website reset data on every day 06:00 PM and when i open website suppose on 01:00pm that time website will appear difference time 05 hrs and when i open website on 06:30 PM that time website will appear difference time 23:30 hrs Everyday.

I have done this with below code. But it gives wrong hrs when i open website in AM.

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$currentDate = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
$redeemDate = $sql->row()->lottery_date . " 18:00:00";

$datetime1 = new DateTime($currentDate);
$datetime2 = new DateTime($redeemDate);
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
```

Comment: `$datetime1 = new DateTime();` is sufficient. The error lies in the passed date.

Comment: `h` = 12h format hours, `H` = 24h format hours, and if you use `h` you also need to pass `AM/PM`, which is `A` (or `a`). See https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php